# Using DeepAR GPU

Tags: time-series, data-science, deepar

I am using Gluonts for building DeepAR model but takes lot of time to run the training object eventhough I use cox = 'gpu' but throws an error. My machine has GPU but the option didn't work. Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You can check your mxnet current version, I believe ur using a CPU version.

please check the following:

```
import mxnet as mx
    print(f'mxnet version: {mx.__version__}')
    print(f'Number of GPUs: {mx.context.num_gpus()}')
```

it should return number of gpus

Comment: Yes you are right I am not using GPU version any idea how to install it?

Comment: first remove your current mxnet version
then install pip install mxnet-cu92 for linux system. Please find https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.4.1/install/index.html?platform=Linux&language=Python&processor=GPU

Answer (score 0):

My takeaways to train GluonTS[mxnet] models using GPU:

1. MXNET only supports  NVIDIA GPU (ex: EC2 g4dn.xlarge)
2. Make sure NVIDIA drivers are properly installed (using an AMI such as "Deep Learning AMI GPU CUDA" was great help for me)
3. Get driver version using `nvcc --version`

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Mon_May__3_19:15:13_PDT_2021 Cuda compilation
> tools, release 11.3, V11.3.109 Build
> cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29920130_0

4. Uninstall mxnet `pip uninstall mxnet`
5. Install mxnet with cuda support according to your driver version `pip install mxnet-cu113`
6. Optionaly, set your trainer with GPU (it should automatically detect the GPU but you may force it)

> ```
> trainer=Trainer(
>         ctx=mxnet.context.gpu(),
>         epochs=train_conf.max_epochs,
>         num_batches_per_epoch=train_conf.num_batches_per_epoch,
>     )
> ```

7. Run your training and check the GPU is being used with `nvidia-smi`
   You should see something like that:

> ```
> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
> |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
> | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
> | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
> |                               |                      |               MIG M. |
> |===============================+======================+======================|
> |   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
> | N/A   32C    P0    37W /  70W |   1101MiB / 15360MiB |     39%      Default |
> |                               |                      |                  N/A |
> +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>
> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Processes:                                                                  |
> |  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
> |        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
> |=============================================================================|
> |    0   N/A  N/A     16057      C   python                           1099MiB |
> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```